# When trying to automate a lighting effect in GIMP using python-fu, my function is throwing a "wrong parameter type" error

Tags: gimp, python-fu

I am trying to run this specific bit of code on the python console of GIMP:

```
pdb.plug_in_lighting(1,img,all_layers[0],0,0,FALSE,FALSE,0,1,[255,255,255],0,0,0,-1,-1,1,0.20,2.15,0.50,0.50,18,0,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)
```

and I keep getting "TypeError: wrong parameter type".

Here's a list of the parameters for the plug-in:

```
 pdb.plug_in_lighting.params
((0, 'run-mode', 'The run mode { RUN-INTERACTIVE (0), RUN-NONINTERACTIVE (1) }'), (13, 'image', 'Input image'), (16, 'drawable', 'Input drawable'), (16, 'bumpdrawable', 'Bumpmap drawable (set to 0 if disabled)'), (16, 'envdrawable', 'Environmentmap drawable (set to 0 if disabled)'), (0, 'dobumpmap', 'Enable bumpmapping (TRUE/FALSE)'), (0, 'doenvmap', 'Enable envmapping (TRUE/FALSE)'), (0, 'bumpmaptype', 'Type of mapping (0=linear,1=log, 2=sinusoidal, 3=spherical)'), (0, 'lighttype', 'Type of lightsource (0=point,1=directional,3=spot,4=none)'), (10, 'lightcolor', 'Lightsource color (r,g,b)'), (3, 'lightposition-x', 'Lightsource position (x,y,z)'), (3, 'lightposition-y', 'Lightsource position (x,y,z)'), (3, 'lightposition-z', 'Lightsource position (x,y,z)'), (3, 'lightdirection-x', 'Lightsource direction [x,y,z]'), (3, 'lightdirection-y', 'Lightsource direction [x,y,z]'), (3, 'lightdirection-z', 'Lightsource direction [x,y,z]'), (3, 'ambient-intensity', 'Material ambient intensity (0..1)'), (3, 'diffuse-intensity', 'Material diffuse intensity (0..1)'), (3, 'diffuse-reflectivity', 'Material diffuse reflectivity (0..1)'), (3, 'specular-reflectivity', 'Material specular reflectivity (0..1)'), (3, 'highlight', "Material highlight (0..->), note: it's exponential"), (0, 'antialiasing', 'Apply antialiasing (TRUE/FALSE)'), (0, 'newimage', 'Create a new image (TRUE/FALSE)'), (0, 'transparentbackground', 'Make background transparent (TRUE/FALSE)'))
```

I just don't know which parameter is wrong...

My hope is to eventually iterate that function over multiple layers to tweaking it a little each time to create a roving spotlight look.

Answer (score 1):

The doc for the Python API is often misleading because it is really the doc for the Scheme API. In particular there is no positional `run-mode` parameter (if you really insists, you can use it as a named parameter), so from the looks of your code your first parameter should be the image.

You can normally get a usable template for the call this way:

- open the Python console (`Filters>Python-fu>Console`)
- hit the "Browse..." button
- search your call (use the search/filter bar at the top of the left panel)
- hit the "Apply" button to have a template for the call copied in the Python console
- execute there (after editing parms) or copy/paste to your code as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I did figure out how to fix my issue.  For the two "bumpdrawable" and "envdrawable" parameters, I was putting 0 since they were disabled.  Well, GIMP didn't like that for whatever reason, so I replaced those 0's with my drawable (i.e., a layer), and it worked.

Comment: You could have used "None"... On the whole, where the Scheme API ised integer IDs, the Python API uses objects, so the equivalent of `0` (no ID) is usually `None` (no object).